# Oracle cloud Infrastructure - what is equivalent component of AWS CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

What is the equivalent component of AWS CloudFormation Template in Oracle Cloud?

I see Oracle Cloud Stack Manager and corresponding templates. However, I don't find them very useful for the scenarios where to launch infrastructure component stack (e.g., with few instances behind a load balancer and with some specific security groups created and attached to them. load balancer listening to specific ports). Oracle cloud stack elements are based on Platform services like Database, Java etc.,

However I tried to edit existing template and didn't find all the resource types for my specific scenario.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/cloud-stack-manager/csmug/list-resource-types.html

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Best option would be to use Terraform. Terraform is an infrastructure as a code tool with similar or I'd say even better capabilities than Cloud Formation.

Try [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/infrastructure-as-code-using-terraform-on-oracle-developer-cloud) to get an idea about working with Terraform and Oracle Cloud.

Comment: Thank you!! I missed to look at terraform. Thats a great option.

Comment: Happy to help @ac184

Comment: Terraform with Resource Manager i would say is the best fit. Create terraform zip keep your variables ready create a Resource Manager stack and provision using OCI Console.